# Single f:viewParam fails validation on postback (ajax) requests on a ViewScoped bean

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, ajax4jsf

I'm passing one request parameter to a facelet page which is processed in the corresponding `preRenderView` event/listener :

```
<ui:define name="metadata">
    <f:metadata>
        <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{essayDetails.id}" />
        <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{essayDetails.init}"/>
    </f:metadata>
</ui:define>
```

Init method is properly accessed and the page is rendered normally. I have a commandLink (RichFaces component) that show a modal panel via an ajax request:

```
<a4j:commandLink rendered="#{essayDetails.comment}" render="create_comment_group" oncomplete="#{rich:component('create_comment_panel')}.show()">
    <h:graphicImage library="images/icons" name="comment.png" />
</a4j:commandLink>
```

The modal panel snippet:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
            xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
            xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
            xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
            xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
            xmlns:utils="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components/utils">

<rich:popupPanel id="create_comment_panel" autosized="true">

    <f:facet name="header">
        <utils:labeledIcon label="#{msg.action_comment}" image="icons/comment.png" />
    </f:facet>

    <h:form>

        <h:panelGroup id="create_comment_group">

            <h:inputTextarea cols="80" rows="8" value="#{essayDetails.userComment}" style="resize: none;" />

            <table style="width: 100%">
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 50%;text-align: right;">
                        <a4j:commandButton  value="#{msg.button_create}" action="#{essayDetails.saveComment}" execute="create_comment_panel_essay" render="essay_comments"  oncomplete="#{rich:component('create_comment_panel')}.hide()" />
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 50%;text-align: left;">
                        <a4j:commandButton value="#{msg.button_cancel}" execute="@none" oncomplete="#{rich:component('create_comment_panel')}.hide()" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </h:panelGroup>

    </h:form>

</rich:popupPanel>
```

In this panel a comment is inserted in a `h:inputTextArea` field, but when the corresponding Accept button is pressed instead of calling `#{essayDetails.saveComment}` method the post-back request fails in validating `f:viewParam` id parameter saying that this fields needs a value.

If we make no changes to original code but adds an extra `f:viewParam`:

```
<ui:define name="metadata">
    <f:metadata>
        <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{essayDetails.id}" required="true" />
        <f:viewParam name="v" value="#{essayDetails.v}" required="true" />
        <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{essayDetails.init}"/>
    </f:metadata>
</ui:define>
```

There is no validation error and the behaviour is as expected. What am I doing wrong in using f:viewParam and/or preRenderView event?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<f:viewParam name="id" value="#{essayDetails.id}" required="#{not facesContext.postback}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try checking in your init() method whether it is a postback:

```
if (!FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().isPostback()) {
    //do your initilialization
}
```

Comment: It is checked properly but the result is as explained above. The only thing that seems to work is to declare 'f:viewParam' with the attribute 'required="false"'. If more than one parameter with attribute 'required="true"' are included in the metadata section there is no problem with postback requests.